# Kivy-How to manipulate the input in kivy using python?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a mobile app using python with KIVY.
In my app the user will give some string type text data as input and the app will have to manipulate the data and show the output to the user.
I can write the python code that will manipulate and change the text data but I don't know how to take it as input and show the changed data as output to the user in kivy.I have used Textinput method but It didn't work.
Can someone help to how can I show the desired output?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post a minimal example demonstrating what you're trying to do, but can't. If you think the question is too complicated to create an example, make an example for a smaller part of it.

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].